# Can dll reference host project's code?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, dll

Can dll code reference its host project's code? (Visual Studio C++)
For example, if host project(A) has T class, I want to make dll project(B) use or create T class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No that's a circular reference. Move T class to project B then both can use.

Comment: Or create a project C that is used by both project A and B